# No module named praw error

Tags: scripts, python, pip

I am currently trying to run a script `change_wallpaper_reddit.sh` which calls `change_wallpaper_reddit.py`. I get this error, however:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sharan/Daily-Reddit-Wallpaper/change_wallpaper_reddit.py", line 7, in <module>
    import praw
ImportError: No module named praw
```

However, when I do a `pip install praw`:

```
Requirement already satisfied: praw in /home/sharan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: decorator<4.1,>=4.0.9 in /home/sharan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from praw)
Requirement already satisfied: update-checker==0.11 in /home/sharan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from praw)
Requirement already satisfied: six==1.10 in /home/sharan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from praw)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.3.0 in /home/sharan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from praw)
```

Now [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415723/unable-to-import-praw-module-after-install) is one resource on **SO**, that deals with this problem, but it is for *Mac OSX* and not *Ubuntu*.

Output of `pip --version`:

```
pip 9.0.1 from /home/sharan/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

Output of `/usr/bin/env python --version`:

```
Python 2.7.13 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Comment: What is the output of `pip --version` and `/usr/bin/env python --version` add these two to your question.

Comment: @Ravexina I have added these two details to the question now.

Comment: Everything seems fine, install praw for both pythons then check see if it works: `sudo apt install python-praw python3-praw`.

Comment: Just did that, and going to restart my computer to see if the script is working.

Comment: Nope, same error.

Comment: open this script `change_wallpaper_reddit.py` at the first line you should see: `#!/usr/bin/env python` change it to `#!/usr/bin/python` save the file. test it again there is no need to reboot the system.

Comment: @Ravexina changed it on my system, doesn't seem to be any change :(

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python` ?

Comment: https://github.com/x89/Shreddit/issues/10 This may be a good place to look to for this problem.

Comment: @Ravexina `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Apr 12 03:46 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7` is the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59673/discussion-between-ravexina-and-sharan-duggirala).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Python 2.7.13 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.` what I can see is that you are running a third party version of python as your default python.

You can change your `PATH` environment variable and give a higher priority to default python:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Or open this file: `change_wallpaper_reddit.py`, it starts with a line similar to: `#!/usr/bin/env python`, change it to `#!/usr/bin/python2.7`.

Save the file and run your script again.

If you get any other error related to modules just install those modules too.

Also install the modules using `apt` instead of `pip` because I believe your pip is installed using the third party python and packages installed using it are not available to your system's python.

Comment: Can you also describe how to change the `PATH` env and I shall accept the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer ...